# Minimizing emerge impact on a low-mem/high load system?

Tags: gentoo

Any best practices on minimizing system performance impact during emerging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use a different system to do the hard work using distcc: http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/distcc.xml

Answer (score 4):

you can set the variable `PORTAGE_NICENESS` in the file `/etc/make.conf`. it sums up a nice value to the emerge process, so that it has less priority on the system. for example:

> PORTAGE_NICENESS=10

the above line, in `/etc/make.conf`, will make portage increment 10 to the default nice value for that process (this will *not* set the nice value to 10, it will increment that value).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from setting PORTAGE_NICENESS Use ionice to reduce impact on hard disk and reduce impact on user.

For example, for installing evolution I would do:

```
ionice -c3 emerge -av evolution
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/). It limits cpu usage per process. So, you can tell emerge to use only 10% of your cpu resources.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark's answer of using distcc sound sgood. Creating binary packages on another system and installing them on the high-load system might be an alternative approach to that one.